# Starting with which version of Delphi is UInt64 not just available but also actually unsigned?

Tags: delphi

Several questions and answers (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20581508) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6378107)) mention that in Delphi 7 the type `UInt64` exists, but contrary to what the name suggests it is a signed 64-bit integer.

What is the minimum version of Delphi that supports *actual properly unsigned 64-bit integers* natively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A true unsigned `UInt64` type was first supported in Delphi 2007.

[QC#1210](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=1210)

Comment: `UInt64` exists as a distinct type in D2006.

Comment: Well, that report was opened for D6 and closed for D2007. I have the RTL source code for D2006 and can see code in the `System` unit related to a distinct `UInt64` data type. And, as the QC report mentions: "*Just a note that Delphi 7 includes an undocumented UInt64 data type that appears to be **partially** functional.  Danny Thorpe has mentioned that not all operators may work with this data type-- hopefully this is addressed in either a patch for D7 or D8.*"  So it was a work-in-progress for awhile. D2007 is probably when `UInt64` was finalized, but is certainly not when it was first added.

Comment: I think the question is about when the type actually first behaved correctly, when it was finalized

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I pointed that out already in my question (that it exists as of Delphi 7). And my question was decidedly about starting when it **behaved** properly as *unsigned 64-bit integer*. Also wonder what *partially functional* is supposed to mean. That it works for half of the range that *should* be supported by unsigned 64-bit integers? ;o)

Answer (score -1):

As it is stated in documentation:

Pre XE4

```
type UInt64 = Int64;
```

XE4

```
type UInt64 = { built-in type };
```

Comment: D2007 did have native support. Also [documented](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/devcommon/simpletypes_xml.html).

Comment: @dustypup: would it be possible to link to the documentation that you're referring to? Also *the* documentation is kind of a stretch, since I do not own XE4 and I am asking precisely because I do not have access to all old and latest versions.

Comment: Documentation is irrelevant here. Or do you want to know at which version the documentation was corrected? I rather imagine that you actually care about which version the compiler was correct. Litmus test is what this program outputs: `{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
begin
  Writeln(low(UInt64));
  Writeln(high(UInt64));
end.
`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: yep, I care about actual behavior, not purely documentation.

Comment: Do you not have old delphi versions. I never had anything between D7 and D2010 so I can't check for you.

Comment: I have Delphi 1.0 thru XE5, so I can check.  But the PC is out of action at the moment while carpets are being fitted.  Can check later hopefully if it's still of interest.

Comment: @Deltics: David pointed to a QC pointing out the exact version. See the accepted answer. But thanks for the offer!